# Bash - using grep on user-defined strings

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

Sometimes I would find it very useful to be able to use grep on a string (without the string being in a file).

For example:

```
var="Some random string"
$var | grep -e "Some"
```

I guess I could use `echo $var | grep ...`, but I don't really want the string to be written on the console.

Comment: `$var | grep -e "Some"` won't work, as Bash expects to find an actual command to execute after expansion - if you try it, you'll see Bash complain that it cannot execute "Some" (unless you happen to have an executable by that name)

Answer (score 2):

`echo $var | grep -e "Some"` is actually the right approach. When piping the output through grep with `|`, it no longer appears on the console. From the [man page of Bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> **Pipelines**
>
> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of
>   the control operators `|` or `|&`. The format for a pipeline is:
>
> ```
> [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|│|&] command2 ... ]
> ```
>
> The standard output of `command` is connected via a pipe to the standard input of `command2`. This connection is performed before any redirections specified by the command (see REDIRECTION). If `|&` is used, the standard error of `command` is connected to `command2`'s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`. This implicit redirection of the standard error is performed after any redirections specified by the command.

Answer (score 2):

bash now allows **here strings**, eg:

```
var="Some random string"
grep -e "Some" <<<"$var"
```